# CORS Support Not working with Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am running a Google Super Proxy project on a local server and trying to pull the JSON query data that is being hosted from a Google appspot website.

```
http://userTest.appspot.com/query?id=ahJzfmNvbm5vcnBoSDfsFEWDSDxsaXBzMjRyFQsSCEFwaVF1ZXJ5GICAgICAgIAKDA
```

The issue I keep running into is that I am not allowed to access this webpage from my local server, because I don't have CORS support. I have tried both JavaScript and JQuery was to enable CORS support, but I'm still getting two error messages in my console. Anyone know what could help?

1)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) http://userTest.appspot.com/query?id=ahJzfmNvbm5vcnBoaWEEWWEWxsaXBzMjRyFQsSCEFwaVF1ZXJ5GICAgICAgIAKDA
```

2)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://userTest.appspot.com/query?id=ahJzfmNvbm5vcnBoaWxsaXBzMjREWEADSdyFQsSCEFwaVF1ZXJ5GICAgICAgIAKDA. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Google Super Proxy Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="chart-options.js"></script>
         <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="sessions-graph" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

chart-options.js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://userTest.appspot.com/query?id=ahJzfmNvbm5vcnBoaWxsaXBzMSDFSDFSjRyFQsSCEFwaVF1ZXJ5GICAgICAgIAKDA',
    contentType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            alert(element.name);
    })
},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
        },

    error: function (json) {
        debugger;
    }
});



    var barChartdata = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: []
            }
        ]
    };


    var options = {

        //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,

        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines : true,

        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke : true,

        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth : 2,

        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing : 5,

        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing : 1,

        //Boolean - Set if responsive or not
        responsive : true

    }

window.onload = function(){

    // Get the context of the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById("sessions-graph").getContext("2d");
    var sessionsGraph = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartdata, options); //Create a chart with "data" array

};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header.

The server you are asking to give you the data has to provide it in the HTTP response. Edit the code responsible for generating `http://userTest.appspot.com/query` to include it.

It does not belong in the request headers. Your script can't give itself permission to access any site.

By making it a request header, you are triggering a preflight OPTIONS request (which is the likely cause of your *method not allowed* error).